# Problem uninstalling License Manager

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-9.3, installation, arcgis-license-manager

If I try to uninstall current version of License Manager (ver 9.3.1) I get the following message:

[image]

This a problem because now I can't install the new version of License Manager for ArcGIS 10. Do you know the solution?

Comment: Additionaly just before ending of installation of AG10 i get this error: http://imgur.com/aLrxX
Maybe it is because i have a previous version of AG on my desktop? Can it be a problem?

Comment: Windows 7 user?

microsoft.vc90.atl processorArchitecture=x86 is a Visual Studio issue

A fix is here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en

Comment: when i try to do it- gives me the same error...(but yes win7 user)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally what happens in that the License Manager sets up your log files to be in a dedicated location, if you are using an operating system newer than XP, it can try to put the logs into your local profile. If then you attempt to install as Administrator it will error.

I would suggest exiting from the installation wizard and then file scanning to the installer location, right click on the installer and then "Run as Administrator" even if you already have admin rights. This should fix your issue.

Comment: Was assuming user had admin rights but yes win7 does change the default location.
Would contact ESRI about the uninstaller bug [with screenshot].

Answer (score 2):

Repair (or re-install) License Manager (on ArcGIS DVD) then remove it via control panel add remove programs. Will replace missing 'Install.log'

Comment: but only if run using the user used to originally install License Manager. This goes back to a change in the UAC for Win7.